# C compiler to build python from sources on various unix flavors

Tags: python, linux, unix, gcc, cross-compiling

Am looking at building python (2.7 version) from sources for various UNIX like OSes including SUSE (Desktop, Server), RHEL (Desktop, Server), Ubuntu, AIX, Solaris (SPARC) OSes.

Also, some of these OSes might have to build both 32 bit and 64 bit versions. I also want to minimize dependencies on (shared) libraries.

That said, is it better to use the native C compiler (cc) wherever available as against gcc? Is it better to cross compile?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the Python source have some sort of configuration script to find available compilers? Also, in many cases the native compiler probably is GCC anyway.

Comment: yes, it does have a configure script. and, it does have some logic of picking the compiler. Defaults to gcc, but on AIX picks the local compiler.

Comment: Your comment to my answer requires this question: Why do you ant to do this? These systems already have Python 2.7 packages available. Somebody else already did this.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that it's better to build on the OS itself, rather than "cross compile". Although since this is all Unix, cross-compiling might very well work as well, with a bit of effort. But it's probably easier to just build the binaries on the OS in question. I guess that also depends on whether you link statically or not.

Python's build process will itself select the best compiler, and it will prefer gcc to cc, at least in most cases.

Comment: Yes, selecting the compiler is done by the configure script. However, my concern is: On my build machine, if the build happens with gcc, and the same binaries are run on same OS on a client's machine, which does not have gcc installed, then might it fail because of gcc related (shared) library dependencies.

Comment: @KiranMN: That's not just gcc related, if you don't link in the libraries in the executable, the libraries has to be installed on the target machine. There are loads and loads of libraries used by Python that this is true for. The solution to that is generally to create a package which also forces the install of the dependencies. But such packages exist already for Python for most (maybe all?) of the targets. So that leaves the simple question: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: We are looking at implementing a new client from the scratch using Python. And, the requirement is to run on various platforms - like Windows (XP, Vista, 7), MAC OS X, Linux (as mentioned above), Solaris (SPARC), AIX (PowerPC) etc.
So, we need a Python runtime to compile and execute our scripts on these platforms. And, usually not all platforms come with python in built, and even if it comes, the versions might differ. Hence, we thought of building & bundling python binaries for UNIX like platforms.

Comment: One more thing is: we want to make sure that the python is built with ssl enabled. (Might not be the case with some pre-installed python)

Comment: @KiranMN: They what you should look at is making packages of your software for the various platforms. On many of them you do not have to install Python but can use the Python that comes with the platform. I would expect (but I'm not sure) that AIX and Solaris are the tricky ones here. Cross-platform compiling will be unlikely to help.